# New Relic - embed chart in custom page without title

Tags: sharepoint, newrelic

I'm trying to embed a series of embedded new relic charts in Sharepoint.  One issue i have is the default embedded link that New Relic uses pulls in the title of the chart.
Is there any way using an iframe link or HTML code to import the embedded link without the title?

I am using Sharepoint to avoid building my own HTML interface.  Eventually i will have a page to show our entire web platform, with other pages tailed for 30 min / 3 hour / 12 hour / 24 hour / 3 day / 7 day time periods etc.   Sharepoint lets me and non techy's lay the page out easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the current embed code feature doesn't allow you to really edit the embed code directly.  I'd file this as a feature request.